# Cannot find windows 10 in grub menu after installing Fedora 24 alongside windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, fedora, grub

I have installed Windows 10 in UEFI mode and then I installed Fedora 24 by shrinking the last partition. But then there is no Windows 10 entry in grub boot menu. I tried adding boot entry in 40_custom file setting root as (hd0,2) and (hd0,3) but both are not working for. I need help with this, my partition details are as below

Please help me with this, need to recover windows 
I tried with (hd0,1) and then (hd0,2) it is not working for me

NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
sda                         8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
 
├─sda4                      8:4    0 146.5G  0 part
 
├─sda2                      8:2    0   100M  0 part
 
├─sda9                      8:9    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sda7                      8:7    0 588.3G  0 part
 
├─sda10                     8:10   0  23.9G  0 part
 
│ ├─fedora_anonymous-swap 253:1    0   2.5G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─fedora_anonymous-root 253:0    0  21.5G  0 lvm  /
├─sda5                      8:5    0  71.7G  0 part
 
├─sda3                      8:3    0    16M  0 part
 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   450M  0 part
 
├─sda8                      8:8    0     1M  0 part
 
└─sda6                      8:6    0 100.2G  0 part

sda1 - windows recovery partition
sda2 - EFI partition
sda4 - windows partition

So how to create grub menu entry for windows 10 that really works.......Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to add Windows to the grub boot entry, you can restore windows 10 bootloader and then add an entry of Fedora in that.

To restore Windows 10 bootloader, you will need a bootable USB/Disk of Windows installation. Boot into it and choose 'Repair your PC'. Then open command prompt and use the commands mentioned here: https://superuser.com/a/1158628/677184

This will make Windows bootloader as default, and you will be able to boot into windows.

To create an entry of Fedora in it, use a small utility "EasyBCD" and this process: https://superuser.com/a/1159368/677184

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried that thing but at last I found my mistake. I installed Windows 10 in UEFI mode but then I installed fedora in legacy mode that caused the problem. I think there is no way I can recover them both, one way is to delete fedora and then trying to restore windows with what you have said. But at last I deleted all partitions and installed fresh. I found no other way suggest any solution if you have some