# May I enable the F8 key function on Windows from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, safe-mode, rescue

I have Windows 10 pro installed on C and it boots but I can no longer access it (the login bar doesn't appear); I want entering the system on safe mode but the F8 doesn't work, I guess it might be disabled by default since I'm on Win 10.

I have a Debian-based distro installed on D too and I can boot other linux distros from usb.

**Is there a way to enable the F8 key on Windows 10 from a Unix-Like environment which can access the C folder?**

Comment: You can edit the hive files with a linux tool like http://libguestfs.org/hivexsh.1.html. You just need to find out which hive file contains the key mappings.

Comment: Windows 10 does NOT use F8 to enter safe mode.   It uses a number of different options to get to safe mode.  An Internet search for `windows 10 safe mode boot` will provide the necessary informatiom

Comment: @fpmurphy1  I already tried all of them but they don't work at all...

Answer (score 1):

This might be one possible solution:
You can rebuild Windows 10 BCD. It will make windows 10 boot menu as default. Then if the linux distros doesn't show up in Windows Bootloader you can add them later using a program called EasyBCD.

To rebuild BCD, boot from Windows 10 installation disk or usb.
When asked to install, choose 'Repair your computer'. Then choose command prompt.
Type these commands:

- bootrec /fixmbr
- bootrec /fixboot
- bootrec /rebuildBCD

Then restart your computer.
F8 can be used (if you still want) when Windows boot menu show up.

Comment: thank you for replying. I followed the procedure but didn't solve the problem...