# Messed up my laptop

Tags: windows-10

I originally wanted to have an SSD of 240gb (Sandisk SSD Plus) to make my current laptop (a Lenovoz40-70) a little bit responsive and faster.

So I bought said SSD and also got a caddy that I can replace it with the slim DVD drive that is in the laptop.

I have already made a Windows 10 bootable USB using the creation tool (probably a month ago) and booted up and chose the SSD and clean install (I wanted a clean system but keeping my HDD intact) I proceeded with the install until it finished. Then it rebooted itself and just hung there for 10 minutes or so...

So then I tried to go to the BIOS and there was only the USB and my HDD , even tried non UEFI... So I just booted back to the USB and it also just froze once it showed the setup screen (where u choose language) and I tried removing everything and only plugging in the HDD and it also did not boot (it gave like a system32 error)...

So now I think that I have messed up my laptop and possibly lost my data on my HDD and I don't know how to try to make a Windows 10 USB from my phone, or should I just buy one?

Comment: Power off completely for 10 mins or so, then check the BIOS again.  Hopefully the power off will reset some switches for you, and you can scan for your SSD drive again in BIOS

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please do not use "Solved" in the title. If an answer has solved your question, accept it by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons to the left of the answer. If you solved it yourself, it is acceptable to answer your own question (as you have). You will eventually be able to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows usually takes longer than 10 minutes or so to install, even on an SSD. If it did install that quickly it could be that the OS installation ran into a problem, and skipped steps.

I've had the problem before. When I tried to install the Windows 10 OS on an external HDD, it said I couldn't install any Windows OS besides Windows 8.1 on it with Win To Go.

Here are a few things you can try:

- You can try to reinstall the OS again on the internal HDD/SSD (whichever you want to use). If you didn't connect the SSD internally, then that may be the problem as well.
- If you connected a new HDD/SDD/SSHD, and tried installing Windows, it could be that the system isn't accepting your original HDD. If this is the case, then I don't think you could successfully boot your OS up again. My solution to that would be to get an enclosure device and copy the files back again to another computer.
- If the computer doesn't work because your HDD/SSD was corrupted, then try installing [Remix OS](http://www.jide.com/remixos) on a computer or use one that already has it. I had a RAW HDD today that couldn't be opened, and that OS did it.

Sorry for the long response but I'm trying to follow every avenue. If any of these were your problems, and you solved them, or they were working up until a point of process at which you failed, then please respond with your issue and myself as well as others can try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so right now I decided to re do the installation and I think it is going well for now...

Before, I did not format my SSD and I thought that it would format it, which is right, but did not think about partitions, so I did a little research and first, I formatted it in the setup from the USB, then deleted primary partition, then created a new partition, so now Windows created two extra partitions, aside from 128 MB from the SSD, it made about 400 MB partition for ms recovery and 100 MB partition reserved for system.

So now installation was fast and it succeeded, thank you all for the help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of things you can try.

- Remove everything, just insert you hard drive back and boot into
  BIOS. Then reset BIOS and save changes, and let the system start.

When do the error appear ?

- If it appears just after manufactures logo (before Windows sign). Then there is a problem in booting your operating system. You need to repair the boot files. boot from Windows USB or DVD and follow the instructions mentioned here: https://superuser.com/a/1158628/677184
- If it appears after windows sign, that means somefiles are somehow corrupted, you can boot from the disk, choose 'repair your system', and see other repair methods like system restore or startup repair, or you can boot to safe mode using advance options.

Don't worry your data is most probably safe, something is wrong just with your operating system.

Now about your SSD. Remove the hard drive from the laptop and insert the SSD carefully, and then try to see it in the BIOS. 
It may be possible that the SSD was loose somehow previously.
If it shows up, install the fresh OS again, and be patient.

If it doesn't, try it in a friends laptop, if it doesn't show up there either, then there could be a problem with your SSD. Contact the manufacturer.